# Split Data into 3 columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that contains people's names.
Using PHP, what's the best way of dividing these names up and displaying them in 3 columns.

This could be achieved using an HTML table, but would it be possible to do this using only `<div>`'s?

I heard that this can be done using the % operator. Would this be the best way, and how would this be done?

Comment: What is the format of the names and how do you want to split them up?

Comment: Have you ever considered to accept an answer?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `<table>`s when dealing with tabular data, you know...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this using the modulus operator, however it's actually possible with just CSS.

Using `display: inline-block`, you can get a good column effect. Take a look at [this JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/MQPRX/). I'm only using JavaScript because I'm lazy; the `<div>` list would be generated by PHP in your case. If you want to confine them to a certain width, just put them in a container `<div>` with a fixed width.

---

I've come up with a solution using tables, which is really what you should be doing (you haven't given any special use cases). The code is below, as well as a working demo [here](http://codepad.org/WlrZaz7R).

```
$columns = 4;       // The number of columns you want.

echo "<table>";     // Open the table

// Main printing loop. change `30` to however many pieces of data you have
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++)
{
    // If we've reached the end of a row, close it and start another
    if(!($i % $columns))
    {
        if($i > 0)
        {
            echo "</tr>";       // Close the row above this if it's not the first row
        }

        echo "<tr>";    // Start a new row
    }

    echo "<td>Cell</td>";       // Add a cell and your content
}

// Close the last row, and the table
echo "</tr>
</table>";
```

---

And to finish off, we have our column-centric layout, this time going back to `div`s. There's some CSS here; this should be put in a separate file, **not left inline**.

```
<?php
$rows = 10;     // The number of columns you want.
$numItems = 30;     // Number of rows in each column

// Open the first div. PLEASE put the CSS in a .css file; inline used for brevity
echo "<div style=\"width: 150px; display: inline-block\">";

// Main printing loop.
for($i = 0; $i < $numItems; $i++)
{
    // If we've reached our last row, move over to a new div
    if(!($i % $rows) && $i > 0)
    {
        echo "</div><div style=\"width: 150px; display: inline-block\">";
    }

    echo "<div>Cell $i</div>";      // Add a cell and your content
}

// Close the last div
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Ideally I would prefer to do this using PHP and the modulus operator, as you should then be able to define how many items should be in each column, and therefore will be able to specify when the data should start being inserted into the next column.

Can you provide some guidance on how this can be done?

Comment: @user826855 Please see my edits above. The code should be fairly self explanatory (I hope). If you've still got questions, don't be afraid to ask.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for that. Is it possible to get it to do it the other way? Rather that fill it by rows (Horizontally), is it possible to do it by columns (Vertically)?

Comment: @user826855 Not sure what you mean. The code above will print your data in 4 columns. Are you saying you want your data in 4 rows of possibly infinite length?

Comment: @user826855 Also, please consider accepting this answer using the tick mark under the rep counter. Please do the same for your other questions; you get free rep, too.

Comment: Umm....Not really. Obviously you will need to define the maximum items a column can contain, but I need the code to to organise the data by column. Saying the maximum items a column could contain was 10, the first column would contain 1-10, the second would contain 11-20, and the third 21-30. Hope that makes better sense!

Comment: @user826855 Got it now. Edited.