# Solving Foreach Rows

Tags: php, foreach

I am looking for help in how to have my foreach loop data display in table rows. The code below echos the data in a single row that runs off the screen. I would like to have three items per row. I currently have about 80 items in total for display and more are added every month so bonus points for anyone who can also help with pagination after 4 rows of 3 items are displayed... FYI, I've tried variations on answers for similar questions asked but I can't find a solution that works for me or I am implementing it wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php foreach (get_terms('term') as $cat) : ?>  
<td>
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'term'); ?>"><strong><?php echo $cat->name; ?></strong></a><br>

<em><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'term'); ?>"><?php echo $cat->description; ?></a></em><br>

<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'term'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" /></a>
</td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

**This is the output produced by Tecbrat's code below:**

```
<table>

<tr>
<td>
<a href="http://comm.org/mag/august-2013/"><strong>August 2013</strong></a><br>

<em><a href="http://comm.org/mag/august-2013/">Issue 101, Vol. 1</a></em><br>

<a href="http://comm.org/mag/august-2013/"><img src="http://comm.org/wp-content/uploads/FC-OCT.jpg" /></a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<a href="http://comm.org/mag/february-2012/"><strong>February 2012</strong></a><br>

<em><a href="http://comm.org/mag/february-2012/">Issue 101, Vol. 1</a></em><br>

<a href="http://comm.org/mag/february-2012/"><img src="http://comm.org/wp-content/uploads/FC-OCT.jpg" /></a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<a href="http://comm.org/mag/february-2013/"><strong>February 2013</strong></a><br>

<em><a href="http://comm.org/mag/february-2013/">Issue 101, Vol. 1</a></em><br>

<a href="http://comm.org/mag/february-2013/"><img src="http://comm.org/wp-content/uploads/FC-OCT.jpg" /></a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<a href="http://comm.org/mag/january-2012/"><strong>January 2012</strong></a><br>

<em><a href="http://comm.org/mag/january-2012/">Issue 101, Vol. 1</a></em><br>

<a href="http://comm.org/mag/january-2012/"><img src="http://comm.org/wp-content/uploads/FC-OCT.jpg" /></a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<a href="http://comm.org/mag/january-2013/"><strong>January 2013</strong></a><br>

<em><a href="http://comm.org/mag/january-2013/">Issue 101, Vol. 1</a></em><br>

<a href="http://comm.org/mag/january-2013/"><img src="http://comm.org/wp-content/uploads/FC-OCT.jpg" /></a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<a href="http://comm.org/mag/november-2013/"><strong>November 2013</strong></a><br>

<em><a href="http://comm.org/mag/november-2013/">Issue 101, Vol. 1</a></em><br>

<a href="http://comm.org/mag/november-2013/"><img src="http://comm.org/wp-content/uploads/FC-OCT.jpg" /></a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<a href="http://comm.org/mag/october-2013/"><strong>October 2013</strong></a><br>

<em><a href="http://comm.org/mag/october-2013/">Issue 101, Vol. 1</a></em><br>

<a href="http://comm.org/mag/october-2013/"><img src="http://comm.org/wp-content/uploads/FC-OCT.jpg" /></a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<a href="http://comm.org/mag/september-2013/"><strong>September 2013</strong></a><br>

<em><a href="http://comm.org/mag/september-2013/">Issue 101, Vol. 1</a></em><br>

<a href="http://comm.org/mag/september-2013/"><img src="http://comm.org/wp-content/uploads/FC-OCT.jpg" /></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**I was able to make it work using this markup:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php $col = 0; ?>
<?php foreach (get_terms('term') as $cat) : ?>

<?php if ($col > 0 && $col % 3 == 0): ?>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $col++; ?>

<td>

<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'term'); ?>"><strong><?php echo $cat->name; ?></strong></a><br>

<em><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'term'); ?>"><?php echo $cat->description; ?></a></em><br>

<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'term'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" /></a>
</td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now I need to find out how to add pagination for every 11 items, so that numbers 12-22 are on page 2, and so on.

Comment: on a UX sidenote: users don't cope well with large tabular data on pages. If this is a webpage, consider finding a different way to do data visualisation. If this is a data resource, then having the data run off the screen should be fine, people who need it know how to use a scrollbar (just ensure your labels are always visible. There are many JS libraries for effective that, just use one of those)

Comment: Thank you for your note. It's for a an online magazine archive so I am trying to display the magazine issues -- preferably four rows of three issues (12 on a page = 1 yr) before paginating to the next page. I'm not sure how else to call the data dynamically but am open to suggestions that are better than the solution I'm trying.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but try this. I just moved your TRs inside the foreach.

```
<table>

<?php foreach (get_terms('term') as $cat) : ?>  
<tr>
<td>
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'term'); ?>"><strong><?php echo $cat->name; ?></strong></a><br>

<em><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'term'); ?>"><?php echo $cat->description; ?></a></em><br>

<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'term'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" /></a>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks... But the data is now appearing vertical -- as a column -- instead of as a row. I am trying to get rows of three, and, if possible for them to be 4 rows of three before paginating to the next page (so each page displays 12 items).

Comment: Do me a favor, please post the output of `var_export(get_terms('term'));` so I can better test the code.

Comment: I just posted the html output above code, beneath your code above. Is that okay?

Comment: @user2591811 its best not to edit TecBrat's post, edit your own post and include the information there.

Comment: Oops, sorry! Will do as you recommend. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I think I need to use a Modulus Operator but am having trouble figuring out how...

Comment: If I have time later and no-one else answers, I'l try to help you more, but in the meantime, see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138954 You're correct about using modulus `%` and that question has an answer using it.

Comment: Thank you TecBrat. That was helpful. With a friend's help I was able to make it work using the code added to my edited post above. Now I need to figure out how to add pagination. I will create a separate question for that and mark this one answered. Thanks for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

The code that worked for my question is:

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php $col = 0; ?>
<?php foreach (get_terms('term') as $cat) : ?>

<?php if ($col > 0 && $col % 3 == 0): ?>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $col++; ?>

<td>

<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'term'); ?>"><strong><?php echo $cat->name; ?></strong></a><br>

<em><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'term'); ?>"><?php echo $cat->description; ?></a></em><br>

<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'term'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" /></a>
</td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
</table>
```